# What would be a good approach to unlimited nested add/edit forms within a rails app/scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, simple-form, rails-admin

#### Overview/Models

Say for example you have a fairly large system with quite generic models (we'll use three for this example)

- Locations (generic address fields, type, line1, line2, towncity etc)
- Companies (generic company fields, type, name, etc)
- Contacts (generic contact fields, tpye, name, jobtitle etc)

#### Example (+ rails_admin screenshot)

I find that when making systems like these I always run into the same problem. I click the add button on a company for example (so I've now loaded the form partial etc), I'm part way through adding a company and find that the location I need is not in the system. I want to quickly open up a modal window, add the location and then update the select via jquery or something along those lines. Great, nothing too tough and it's been done in systems like rails_admin (see screenshot below):

http://www.server1-breakfrom.com/nestedaddexample.jpg

This is all good when dealing with one level of nesting, and generally speaking all good when dealing with this as a rarity (as you can program in the ability as and when). However, I'm doing a system where this almost needs to be a framework in itself as I need it in over 50% of the models. I need the ability to dynamically add the various options in the model/controller and have the forms dynamically generate the relevant buttons.

#### Additional Issues

1. Modals within/on top of modals - When adding a contact, you click to add their company, within this new companies add form you then want to add a location: boom, modal on top of modal.
2. What text to jquery append to the select - You need to know how to update the select element and possibly to find all the relevant select elements on screen. Adding a company will use it's ID and it's name perhaps, but a location will need to use ID along with maybe line1,line2 and towncity for the text.
3. Validation within the modal (but I assume we can use some sort of jquery since we're already very dependant on it)

#### Expanding the question

So, in addition to the question: Am I over complicating things and is there an easy to to solve my issue (I must stress the 3 models are purely examples, I have many models that need to reference a company for example, it's not just a contact so 'just program it as you need it', will not work!).

Or, should I just pull apart rails_admin and pull out the bit I need? (Again, they have not solved the multiple nesting issue so I feel a start from scratch might be better?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solving the problem

After a lot of testing and going through the code kindly submitted by RadBrad, I accidentally stumbled across a Gem with an answer to almost exactly what I expected from the question/phrase 'dynamic nested forms (with jQuery)'. 'Unlimited', it seems, was a poor choice of word for the original question but hopefully this text will get the question picked up a bit better on the search engines.

#### The Gem

That Gem is called Cocoon and can be found here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

#### Extras

As a bonus it is built using jQuery, compatible with simple_form, formtastic and also fits quite well into Twitter Bootstrap!

#### Additional Notes

I've not fully tested it and to be brutally honest, validation already looks to be a minor issue but I will update this answer further if I find anything that doesn't work as expected.

The example github projects provided by Cocoon are pretty outdated and you'll need to do a lot of re-jigging in the Gem file to get them to work (but it is do-able!). Rest assured the main Gem (at the time of writing this) is up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar situation.  My solution may have performance issues in your scenario,  it didn't for me but it's a low concurrent usage system, only 300 total users.

What I did was go with one MEGA AJAX view/form! and use JavaScript to show/hide as needed.  This technique requires that you NOT use the form tag helpers (i.e. text_field_tag instead of f.text_field) an YOU have to take control of the element names.

So start out creating a single view with all of the forms  you'll eventually need.       You'll have to distinguish them so put each one in a div element with a unique ID.

```
<%= form_for @mega, :remote=>true do %>
  <div id='main_part'>
    <%= render :partial => "main_part", :object=>@mega  %>
  </div
  <div id='subpart1'>
    <%= render :partial => "subpart1" , :object=>@foobar , :locals=>{:id=>@foobar.id} %>
  </div
  <div id='subpart2'>
    <%= render :partial => "subpart2" , :object=>@barfoo , :locals=>{:id=>@barfoo.id} %>
  </div
<% end %>
```

An example of the form partials, taking care to distinguish the submit buttons:

```
<%= label_tag "main_part[name]" ,"Name" %>
<%= text_field_tag "main_part[name]" , main_part.name %>
<%= submit_tag "UPDATE", :name=>'main_part' %>

<%= hidden_tag_field "subpart1_id" , id %>
<%= label_tag "subpart1[city]" ,"City" %>
<%= text_field_tag "subpart1[city]" , subpart1.city%>
<%= submit_tag "ADD", :name=>'subpart1' %>
```

So now you'd need a mega controller,  because this one form posts to a single controller action. This controller would look like a regular controller for your top level model only,  but it will need to do the housekeeping for ALL the models.

That controller action has to figure out which submit button was clicked, i.e.

```
def update
  if params[:main_part]
    # since I controlled the parameter naming I know what's in params[:main_part] 
    # which is main_part[:name]
    @mega = MainThing.find(params[:id])
    @mega.attributes = params[:main_part]
    @mega.save
    # only for main_part is the id valid,  in every other case you have to 
    # manually extract the id
  elsif params[:subpart1]
    @subpart1_id = params[:subpart1_id]
    @foobar = FooBar.find(@subpart1_id)
    @foobar.attrubutes = params[:subpart1]
    @foobar.save
  else
  end
end
```

Since the mega form is remote=>true,  you need to create a javascript file that will reload all your form partials,  so in app/views/megas/update.js.erb:

```
$('#main_part').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=> "main_part", :object=>@mega) %>');
$('#subpart1').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=> "subpart1", :object=>@foobar :locals=>{:id=>@foobar.id) %>');
```

Now here is where the performance issues comes in.  If you notice,  if I run that javascript,  it will expect all these instance variables be defined,  so the various partial will render refreshing any select tags that got new values as a result of the update.  In my case I just load them all up,  in a before filter, i.e.

```
class MegaController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load, :only=>[:edit]
  def load
     @mega = Mega.find(params[:id])
     @foobar = @mega.foobar
     @barfoo = @foobar.barfoo
  end
```

But you could also NOT to that, and instead create individual javascript files and render them specifically in the controller, i.e.

```
def update
  if params[:main_part]
    # do whatever...
    render :action=>'update_set1', :handler=>[:erb], :formats=>[:js]
  elsif params[:subpart1]
    # do whatever
    render :action=>'update_set1', :handler=>[:erb], :formats=>[:js]        
  elsif params[:subpart2]
    # do whatever
    render :action=>'update_set2', :handler=>[:erb], :formats=>[:js]        
  end
end
```

The file app/views/mega/update_set1.js.erb  would only update the partials affected by an update to @mega or @foobar,  update_set2.js.erb would update partials affected by an update to @barfoo.

Last point,  you're form is remote=>true,  how do you exit?  Assuming you have:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Cancel', :name=>'cancel' %>
```

Then in a controller you'd do something like:

```
 def update
   if params[:cancel]
      render :js=> "window.location = '/'"
   else
      # whatever....
   end
 end
```

The last step is to add javascript to show/hide the form divs as needed, an exercise left to the reader....

UPDATE

```
class Mega < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.get_param_name
      self.class.name
   end

   def self.get_id_name
      "#{self.class.name}_id"
   end
end

class MyModel < Mega
end
```

then in a mega controller:

```
def edit
   @mymodel = MyModel.find(params[MyModel.get_id_name])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding some more light on the various techniques I can use @RadBrad.

The only issue I can see is that it still isn't as dynamic as I want it (I'm well aware that I probably want something extremely complicated). For adding a contact, and allowing someone to add a company and location at the same time, this approach works well from what I have tested, however, you need to start the process again and create a new set of 'mega' files for when a user wants to start the process at adding a company and having only a location as a subpart.

Comment: wouldn't that just be a matter of jquery hiding divs?  An possibly the logic you use to decide which partials get re-rendered?

Comment: OK, so basically what your solution is doing is saying that we have X models, and every single one of those models that we might need to use will be going into our mega AJAX form. So that's the dynamic side of that done (let's forget about performance for now!). We can specify (along the same lines of hiding and showing) which is the main model for the add, but is there any easy way of not having to write a huge controller (I assume we have to add to this huge controller every time we add a new model)? Could we have a mega controller that then pulls in the various controllers that it needs?

Comment: How about a mega model that all your models inherit from?  With one mega controller.  The sub models would inherit methods that generate, I don't know what to call them,  control_stubs, relative to the name of the subclass,  then the mega controller only needs to know the new model name.

Comment: Yes that's making more sense now, I'm quite new to Rails, moving from PHP so I'm going to need to do a bit of testing and come back with some more solid answers I think (as I really want to try to get a solid dynamic answer to this problem). I unfortunately can't up vote your answer because I don't have the 15 rep required but will do so as soon as I do as it's been very helpful!

Comment: I added an update to explain the mega controller and self describing models idea.